# @ElementCollection with @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I used to have an `@ElementCollection` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the database level generated by hibernate as follows:

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "project2user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"))
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<Long> users;
```

In the latest Hibernate 6.4.4 it does not work anymore. It complaints that:

*'@ElementCollection' is directly annotated '@JoinColumn' (specify '@JoinColumn' inside '@JoinTable' or '@CollectionTable')*

and if I remove the `@JoinColumn` on the fourth line, it says

*'@OnDelete' must explicitly specify a '@JoinColumn'*

Is there any way to define the `ON DELETE CASCADE` in DDL generation? `foreignKeyDefinition` is unfortunately not suitable as the schema name is not known at the time of compilation and it must be added to the constraint automatically.